# Modulo on massive numbers

Tags: math, large-data, modulus

In the case I have two numbers large enough to justify using scientific notation twice
(A * 10^(B * 10^C))
or Ae+Be+C
How would I calculate Modulo without taking the numbers or any part of them out of scientific notation?

Comment: I think [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) will help you.

Comment: You need this algorithm https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation